# Could not mount iPhone after Restore - 14.04

Tags: mount, iphone

I am using 14.04 and an iPhone 3GS running iOS 6.1.6. All was working fine out of the box until I decided to restore my iPhone to the same version of iOS on a windows machine. After doing that Ubuntu doesn't mount my iPhone and I get an error "Unable to connect".

[image]

So far I tried reinstalling `libimobiledevice4` using synaptic package manager and also tried to install `libimobiledevice-utils` (`sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils;idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair && idevicepair validate`)

unpair - gives me an error saying that device is not paired, pair and validate are working but the phone does not mount anyway.

Is there any other solution besides reinstalling Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

i'm a Kubutu User, my problem was related to this error when try to use iFuse:

```
GNUTLS ERROR: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
```

To solve this, i did the following:

1. Open Konsole
2. type this:

   ```
   sudo idevicepair unpair
   ```
3. then type:

   ```
   sudo usbmuxd
   ```
4. try to run iFuse with sudo:

   ```
   sudo ifuse /media/iPhone/ --root
   ```
5. Now open Dolphin with kdesudo as follows:

   ```
   kdesudo dolphin
   ```
6. Navigate to /media/iPhone/ now, you should see the root files.
7. To unmount your device, use:

   ```
   sudo fusermount -u /media/iPhone/
   ```

**Remember to unmount your device before unplug it!**

8. This worked again when i restored my iPhone 3G to Whited00r7.1.
9. Also, you can set permissions to ifuse and fusermount, using chmod 777 ifuse, and chmod 777 fusermount, so, the next time you will not have to use "sudo".

Now, you can mount you iPhone 3G. The usbmuxd is used only the first time. The next time you want to mount your iphone, typing usbmuxd is not needed.

I hope this helps. I use Kubuntu 14.04.1 x64

Answer (score 0):

I got an error on `sudo idevicepair unpair`
I did `sudo idevicepair` and that worked.  Then I was able to do `sudo idevicepair unpair` and `sudo usbmuxd`.  Next I unpluged my phone form the USB and when I repluged it mounted.  Thanks!